# When and why product guid has to be changed for upgrades?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield, wix3.5

Recently i did small update via msp, my team lead instructed me not to change project guid.

As it fails to update the installed files ,we changed product GUID and it installed the files correctly.

I would like to know when product guid should be changed and why we are changing that?

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367850.aspx) should answer your question. The excerpt you are asking about:

> The product code must be changed if any of the following are true for
>   the update:
>
> - Coexisting installations of both original and updated products on the same system must be possible.
> - The name of the .msi file has been changed.
> - The component code of an existing component has changed.
> - A component is removed from an existing feature.
> - An existing feature has been made into a child of an existing feature.
> - An existing child feature has been removed from its parent feature.

Besides, I'd suggest you to read [the entire section about patching and upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370579.aspx) thoroughly.